# Java swagger annotations for authorization

Tags: java, authorization, swagger

I'm using following swagger dependencies for my rest api:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.17.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I'm adding security to my project. How can I implement the possibility to use api from swagger?

I can set `@HeaderParam(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)` for each method - but I guess there is better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So now I want to share with you working solution I used:

```
@SwaggerDefinition(securityDefinition = @SecurityDefinition(
    apiKeyAuthDefinitions = {
            @ApiKeyAuthDefinition(
                    key = HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
                    name = HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
                    in = ApiKeyAuthDefinition.ApiKeyLocation.HEADER
            )
    }
))
```

It's gonna create security button for your Swagger UI to set auth header. Now you just need to annotate the apis you want to secure like this:

```
@Api(value = "Your value", description = "Your description", authorizations = {
    @Authorization(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)
})
```

Of course you can use your custom header, but for my solution I used `HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION`.

So I hope it's gonna help to someone.